# How to evaluate a sql string stored in excel column using SQL Server Integration Services?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I know how to insert data from excel columns to a table (I followed a very basic tutorial, use an excel source, data conversion and ole db destination).

But my problem is a little more elaborate, I have ~ 100 excel files where has stored in  E column a SQL string created with `=concatenate("insert into same table (", If(B2 > ...), C2 , ")";`

Using a Integration ServicesI want to execute the value of column E of every excel file.

```
|A   |B   |C        |D   |E                          |
|Juan| 200| 'Activo'| ...|'insert into sometable ...'
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: you need to use dynamic SQL , extract columnE from each of the tables and execute

Comment: What is the purpose of the E column and what does it really contain ?

Comment: @Steam The column E store a sql insert statement made it using the excel formula  ´=concatenate(""´

Comment: It sounds like you have a query that is fully formed in a column in an excel sheet.  Are there multiple rows in the sheet, each with their own queries?  Or is it just one query per Excel file?  In either case, you can use the SSIS foreach loop to accomplish your goal -- looping either through the files, extracting the query by filename, or looping through rows with "Foreach ADO Enumerator".  Within the loop, execute your sql statement.

Comment: @ErickAstoOblitas - Its been a while since I worked on SSIS. Try to iterate over each row. Store the value of E column of a row in a SSIS variable. Then, execute the SQL in the SSIS variable using execute sql task. Does that help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to make sure that the column E has a header. Inside a for each loop container, just extract that 1 column (which has your query) and store it within a string variable. Now within this For Each loop container, put in a Execute SQL Task and use the Dynamic SQL to execute the query. The caveat to this is that once the package fails, you will need to know on what statement it failed so that you don thave repeat the whole process. And if there are any spurious values, your DB's would be bombed.